# How to amend Gradle plugins {} management repository for custom plugins?

Tags: java, gradle

My company proxy/firewall settings are blocking `jcenter` and `mavencentral` etc, therefore, I can't get Gradle **custom** plugins from GitHub.

I'm using gradle 4.7 and still using that old way of getting plugins with `buildscript{}` - which is `Gradle 1.x`. I would like to use `plugins{}` and just put id's inside that block but I can't because of the default repository is trying to fetch it from.

**Is there a way to amend plugins repo?** Maybe in `init.gradle` or a cmd arg?

Or maybe just add another one to look at. I found a few links but those already expired and my last resort would be just to check the source code. I hope there is a simple answer to this.

**Gradle 2.1 and higher** want to use this

```
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.4.3"
}
```

**Gradle 1.x and 2.0** using this at the moment

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mynexusrepo()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.4.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. It changed a few times already but for the 4.7 version of Gradle, this looks like a working solution.

> Remember that some of the plugins need to be in GString "" !

**This need to be in `settings.gradle` as the first block to work.**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://cdlnexus01:8081/nexus/content/groups/GradlePlugins/" }
        maven { url "http://cdlnexus01:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
}
```