# Could not find bundletool-1.11.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I Got this error after installing Android Studio

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'afsar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.11.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.11.0/bundletool-1.11.0.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I added these lines to gradle but not work:

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
jcenter()
```

Finally I downloaded **bundletool-1.11.0.jar** file but I don't know where to paste it. please help!

> **Answer:**
> I selected the latest version of gradle for my app and my problem was solved!!!

```
gradle-version: 8.0-rc-2
Android-gradle-plugin-version: 7.4.0-beta04
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't HAVE to download dependencies manually.  Usually, when Gradle can't find an existing artifact from a well-known repo, it's just a sign that you have some network issue going on (i.e., proxies, firewall, other network security).  If you can point a web-browser to `https://www.gradle.org`, you should be able to have Gradle do the downloading for you if you sort out the real problem.

Some things that might help are replacing `jcenter()` (now non-existent--see here: ["JCenter is at end of life" android lint warning, what is the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400264/jcenter-is-at-end-of-life-android-lint-warning-what-is-the-replacement) ) with something like `mavenCentral()`, and perhaps the `maven.google.com` with its shortcut, `google()`.

Then, check your proxy settings in `gradle.properties` (perhaps with the answers here: [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration) ).

But, if you do have an artifact **in hand**, and you just want to use it, you can use the `flatDir` inside of `repositories { ... }`, such as described here:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver
- [Gradle build using plugins and dependencies from "flatDir"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797206/gradle-build-using-plugins-and-dependencies-from-flatdir)

`flatDir` uses a path specified as a "repository".  Together, it might look like:

```
repositories {
  google(); mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  flatDir {
    dirs "${projectDir}/libs"
  }
}
```

This will look in multiple existing repositories, as well as search the folder `libs/` in your project for the local copy of the `.jar`.

Comment: thanks. your answer may help someone. I have done everything you said before...