# Can we give Gradle plugin in code base as JAR file

Tags: gradle

Can we give Gradle plugin in code base as JAR file, rather than downloading from Internet ?
Below plugin I am using in my application.

```
plugins {

    id 'red.sukun1899.wanko' version '1.0.7'
    id 'net.saliman.properties' version '1.5.1'
    id 'io.errorlab.gradle.vault' version '0.1.0'
}
```

Please guide me how can i use as JAR file rather than download all the time from internet.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61209978/6899896

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add local .jar file dependency to build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)