# Why Android Studio fails to apply plugin 'com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git'?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, semantic-versioning

Could some sharp eye find what has been bugging me for the last week?
I cloned this repo but build fails with this exception:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\repos\project\Launcher\git.gradle" line: 4
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   Failed to apply plugin 'com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git'
>
> Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\repos\project\Launcher"): CreateProcess error=2, System cannot find specified file

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "check.gradle"

buildscript {

    ext.buildConfig = [
            "sdkCompile" : 31,
            "sdkMinimum" : 19,
            "sdkTarget"  : 28,
            "tools"      : "30.0.2",
            "versionCode": 1549,
            "versionName": "1.0.14",
    ]

    ext.versions = [
            "kotlin"  : "1.3.72",
            "okhttp"  : "3.12.12", // This version is the latest supporting API 19
            "retrofit": "2.6.4", // This version is the latest supporting API 19
            "room"    : "2.2.5",
    ]

    ext.lib = [
            "androidx": [
                    "appcompat"    : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0",
                    "async_inflate": "androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0",
                    "cardview"     : "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0",
                    "constraint"   : "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3",
                    "core"         : "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1",
                    "fragment"     : "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5",
                    "material"     : "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0",
                    "multidex"     : "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1",
                    "preference"   : "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1",
                    "swipe_refresh": "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0",
                    "work"         : "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0",
            ],
            "date"    : [
                    "core": "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.4",
            ],
            "debug_db": "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6",
            "firebase": [
                    "analytics": "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4",
                    "crash"    : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1@aar",
            ],
            "glide"   : "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0",
            "viewpage": [
                    "indicator": "com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3@aar",
            ],
            "kotlin"  : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${versions.kotlin}",
            "kb_event": "net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.3.0",
            "okhttp"  : [
                    "core"   : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${versions.okhttp}",
                    "curl"   : "com.github.mrmike:ok2curl:0.4.5",
                    "logging": "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${versions.okhttp}",
            ],
            "play"    : [
                    "location": "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0",
            ],
            "retrofit": [
                    "core": "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${versions.retrofit}",
                    "gson": "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${versions.retrofit}",
            ],
            "room"    : [
                    "compiler"  : "androidx.room:room-compiler:${versions.room}",
                    "core"      : "androidx.room:room-runtime:${versions.room}",
                    "coroutines": "androidx.room:room-ktx:${versions.room}",
            ],
            "timber"  : "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1",
    ]

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${versions.kotlin}"
        classpath "com.cinnober.gradle:semver-git:2.5.0"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.0.0"
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.29.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${rootProject.rootDir}/libs"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task sendHomologToFirebase {
    group = "Firebase"
    dependsOn "Launcher:assembleHomologRelease"
    finalizedBy "Launcher:appDistributionUploadHomologRelease"
}

task sendProductionToFirebase {
    group = "Firebase"
    dependsOn "Launcher:assembleProductionRelease"
    finalizedBy "Launcher:appDistributionUploadProductionRelease"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my `git.gradle`:

```
ext.nextVersion = "patch"
ext.snapshotSuffix = "<count><dirty>"
ext.dirtyMarker = ".d"
apply plugin: "com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git"

task git_count {
    def process = ("git rev-list --count HEAD").execute(null, project.rootDir)
    process.waitFor()
    if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
        ext.count = 0
        return
    }
    ext.count = process.text.trim().toInteger()
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

Both solutions described in this [Gradle semver-git plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git/2.5.0)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.com.cinnober.gradle:semver-git:2.5.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git"
```

And:

```
plugins {
  id "com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git" version "2.5.0"
}
```

Also tried directly downloading the `.pom` file and loading it locally using:

```
flatDir {
    dirs "${rootProject.rootDir}/libs"
}
```

I even tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54918583/using-gradle-plugin-from-flatdir-source) from another SO answer:

Including this on my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.cinnober.gradle.semver-git'
}
```

And including this on my `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs '/libs'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath ':semver-git:2.5.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you mentioned some things you tried to do to fix it yourself.  The error message seems fairly clear saying that git doesn't exist at that path.  Have you tried correcting that?

Comment: Ok, updated with my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the error message is likely the end:

> Cannot run program "git" (in directory
> "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\repos\project\Launcher"): CreateProcess
> error=2, System cannot find specified file

It's saying that it tried to run the program git but couldn't find it.  It seems the plugin tries to run git as part of the process of applying it and it failed while doing so.

You already have git somewhere on your system since you cloned the repo, but it likely hasn't been added to your PATH so the script can't find it when it tries to run the command `git`

1. The first step is to find where the git executable is on your system.
2. Assuming that you're on windows, you will want to edit your system environment variables.  It should be under `Windows Settings` -> `System Environment Variables` -> `Path`.  Edit the `Path` variable by appending the full path to the folder your git executable is in.
   i.e: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` if that's where your git.exe lives.
3. Restart android studio afterwards to force it to load the new environment variables.

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/git-installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows) which has more detailed instructions about how to add git to the PATH with detailed examples.